# What are the most difficult/computationally expensive/infeasible derivatives to price?

Tags: monte-carlo, derivatives, valuation

I'm not sure if this question has a concrete answer or if it's more of a fun game, but I suppose the question that does have a concrete answer is what's the most difficult instrument to value that has actually been traded OTC?

For the game part of it, what is the most difficult thinkable instrument to value, and if there are several completely impossible then what is the "least complex" but still impossible to value theoretical instrument?

As a start I was considering something like a Best-Of option (or any rainbow option) (typically suited for Monte Carlo valuation) but allowing for early exercise (typically not suited for Monte Carlo valuation). Can something like this be valued and how would you do it?

Comment: As far as computationally expensive goes, that is more computer science than anything quant finance. This post on Medium may help you to understand a bit: https://medium.com/swlh/an-introduction-to-big-o-notation-time-complexity-2d2019a9772

Comment: How about a derivative that pays \$1 if $P=NP$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Well, aren't you a funny guy (actually was pretty fun, not gonna lie).

Comment: Is this not a "the sky is the limit" type of question? Just use your imagination and I am sure you can think of one derivative nastier than the next to price?

Comment: Well that's where the second paragraph comes in then, which derivative has the highest nasty-to-price to easy-to-describe ratio. Would be fun to see some examples of what people can think up